# JavaScript - split and join in between string using filter

Tags: javascript, string, join, split

I have to convert all paths from settings/user/account/profile to settings/user1/account/profile. Below is how new paths are currently being generated but "user1" is placed at the end. How do I place it between "settings" and "account"?

Is there a cleaner way of using another split statement to place "user1" in between settings and account?

```
export const generateUrl = () => {
    let alt = "";
    let path = "settings/user/account/profile";
    let newPath = path
        .split("/")
        .filter((path) => {
            if (path === "account") {
                alt = "/user1";
            }
            return path && !/^(user)$/.test(path);
        })
        .join("/");
    return `${newPath}${alt}`;
);
```

Comment: Just use `let newPath = path.replace('user','user1')` and return `newPath`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, map is a better function to use, since you want to modify the original array

```js
const generateUrl = () => {
  let alt = "";
  let path = "settings/user/account/profile";
  let newPath = path
    .split("/")
    .map((path) => (path === "user" ? 'user1' : path))
    .join("/");
  return `${newPath}${alt}`;
};

console.log(generateUrl())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change it.

```js
let path = "settings/user/account/profile";
let res = path.split('/').map(x => x === 'user' ? 'user1' : x).join('/');
console.log(res);
```

However, it is far easier to directly use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
let path = "settings/user/account/profile";
let res = path.replace('user', 'user1');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

filter returns `true` or `false`. if returns `true` it uses value else it passes value. Your filter is always returns initial path without **"user"** and you added alt after `path`.
just try like this.

```js
    let path = "settings/user/account/profile";
    let newPath = path
        .split("/")
        .map((path) => {
            return path === "user" ? "user1" : path;
        })
        .join("/");
    console.log( `${newPath}`);
```